# How to add or generate a missing keyframe at the beginning of converted video in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

There is a MP4 file representing a downloaded stream transmission from which I want to extract a program that starts after the beginning and ends before end of this MP4 file. I cut the unwanted parts off by two simple ffmpeg 'conversions'. In the first step, I cut off the tail:

```
ffmpeg -i stream_record.mp4 -c copy -t 1:26:33.15 cut_record.mp4
```

The second step is to cut off the unwanted beginning, but here I run into problems. E.g. after

```
ffmpeg -i cut_record.mp4 -c copy -ss 02:36 final_record.mp4
```

I quite often get a file with no video in the beginning (up to 6 seconds), only audio is playing. This is because after skipping the time specified in `-ss` option there is no keyframe in the video stream and it takes up to those 6 seconds to find the first one. Unfortunately, my desired part of the downloaded stream quite seldom starts with a keyframe, and I must keep some part of the video preceding my program to maintain video integrity in the beginning of the file.

Is there a method in FFMPEG to add something (e.g. black rectangle) as the first keyframe right at the start of the copied video stream? I mean, other than completely recoding the video stream (I would like to keep the `-c copy` parameter in the process)?

I could probably achieve the desired result using Openshot Editor - but it recodes the video and audio, takes relatively long time and consumes much CPU and memory resources.

Comment: Place `-ss` before `-i`. The output should work as expected in decent players. Add `-avoid_negative_ts make_zero` before the output URL if it doesn't.